# iotop shows 99.8% IO load on "--render" and "--extension" and "dropbox \fataldb" processes

Tags: hard-drive, dropbox, top, io

folks.

System works more or less fine, but stucks from time to time. I've tried to detect using `iotop` it and it seems that disk io is the bottleneck.

`chrome` and `jbd2` keep writing to disk all the time, but load not more than 5-15% of IO

From time to time (more than once an hour) processes with names like `--render-print-preview ..` or `--extension ..` or `dropbox \fataldb` or `chrome --no-startup-window` load > 99% of IO for a few seconds and during that time system is totally unresponsive - it just stucks so hard that I can't even open console and tty1 (Ctr-Alt-1) .

Any ideas of why it can behave like this? Thanks.

**update**: it seem that those 99% load is 3-5Mb/s that seems quite little. However, tests like `hdpram` and `dd -if=/dev/sda -of=/dev/null` show read speed at about 70Mb/s - and that's normal. May be the thing is that they are sequential.

Comment: Try adding the output of `sudo iotop -n 1 |head` to your question, so people can see what's going on. Fair chance there is another process causing the writing, and jdb2 is just handling that. See also http://askubuntu.com/questions/306626/jbd2-constantly-writing-to-disk and http://askubuntu.com/questions/444033/100-i-o-usage-due-to-jbd2