# Stop jbd2 writing to hdd

Tags: hard-drive, fstab

I have `/dev/sdb` as a storage drive. (used very rarely) I would like to use TLP or hdparm to power it off when not used to save power. However when I monitor disk's activity with `watch iostat -d /dev/sdb` i see something constantly writing into the disk. With `iotop` I can see `jbd2/sdb2-8` running all the time. How could I disable this?

I've added `noatime` option to /etc/fstab.

The problem starts immediatly after I reboot. IO percentage of `jbd2/sdb2-8` is less than 0,05. The only problem is that because it is writing some small amounts of data, tlp won't power the HDD off.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jbd2 constantly writing to disk](http://askubuntu.com/questions/306626/jbd2-constantly-writing-to-disk)

Comment: For me usage is only <0,05 %. Also in my case, it starts immediatly after reboot.

Comment: im having problems with it as well. at the very least, jbd2 should have a man page. it is confusing as to what it is doing, why, how, etc.